# Nagios check_nrpe does not work with Perl DBD::Oracle

Tags: oracle, perl, nagios

```
[nagios@nagios-prod libexec] ./check_nrpe -H dbprod10 -c check_ohc_tnsping
```

> CRITICAL - cannot connect to NREP11. install_driver(Oracle) failed:
> Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for
> module DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file:
> No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 200.
> at (eval 19) line 3 Compilation failed in require at (eval 19) line 3.
> Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where
> expected at /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_oracle_health line 6088

But when I try `locate Oracle.so` I see this in place:

```
[nagios@nagios-prod libexec] locate Oracle.so
/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so
```

Permissions also seems to be right:

```
[nagios@nagios-prod libexec] ls -al /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 649370 Nov 24 11:04 /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so
```

Anyone got any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`ldd /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so`

most probably you do not have set

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ORACLE_HOME}/lib
```

Comment: Environment vars are set:
[root@nagios-prod ~]# set | grep ora
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64

Oracle.so also seems to see libclntsh.so:
[root@nagios-prod ~]# ldd /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so
linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007fff8ebf3000)
libocci.so.12.1 => /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libocci.so.12.1 (0x00007f1a5debc000)
libclntsh.so.12.1 => /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 (0x00007f1a5aefe000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0...